# View my value in the top and the rest by

Tags: c#, linq

This is how I print something to the drop-down list, and when you have the right content, value to the user has selected in the beginning.

it means that the user's content located at the top and after the rest will come forth.

the problem is right now: it only shows the selected value above and do not show the rest forward.

```
DWkategoriRet.DataSource = from p in db.kategoris
                           where p.id == 1
                           orderby 0
                           select new
                               {
                                  Id = p.id,
                                  navn = p.navn
                               };
DWkategoriRet.DataTextField = "navn";
DWkategoriRet.DataValueField = "id";
DWkategoriRet.DataBind();
```

so it should do is to remove the selected value first and after, the roof rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure on this one, but that linq query looks like it is gonna give only one value, which has `id==1`

As for the rest of the question if I've understood it right you want the selected item to be first followed by the rest. This code should do that

```
 db.kategoris.OrderByDescending(p => p.id == 3).ThenBy(p => p.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for help!. i hope u will giv me +1 for my ask :)